# Python Flask not receiving AJAX post?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I have run into a problem with my javascript/python script. What I am trying to do is pass a string to python flask so I can use it later. When I click the button to send the string, there are no errors but nothing happens. I am basically a self taught coder so I apologise if my script it not properly formatted!

Javascript:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
$.ajax({
   url:"/",
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   ...
```

Python Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        string = request.args.get(data)
        print(string)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to be able to see the string printed to either the console or the command prompt, I assume print() is the right way to do this?
Any help would be welcome, thank you :)

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an ajax POST request like this:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/",
         method: "POST",
         data: { paramter : value },
       });
```

The data send over this POST request can be accessed in flask app with`request.form['parameter']`

If you are sending raw json data, you can access the data by  `request.json['parameter']`

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/",
         method: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify("{'paramter': 'value'}"),
         contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
       });
```

And this should work.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is in `request.data`.

`request.args` contains parameters in the URL.

Check this out for more details. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#incoming-request-data

Answer (score 1):

If you data object in Ajax is json then you can use `request.get_json()`

If it is form data of key value then you can `request.form.get('data')` but your ajax should be

```
$('#button').click(function() {
$.ajax({
   url:"/",
   type: 'POST',
   data: {data: 'mystring'},
```